Include Files is not working in ESLint 9+
I'm using ESLint 9.7.0 and I want to implement ESLint on a specific folder in my React app. But it's not working on the folder I'm giving the path of that folder in my eslint.config.mjs. Here is my eslint.config.mjs file:
export default [
  {
    files: ["src/components/workplace/**/*.js"],
  }
]

Here is my ESLint command in package.json:
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint ."
  }
}

I know by giving the folder or path in package.json it will work but it should pick that from the config file.

What exactly "not working" implies? Nothing get linted? Error thrown? Everything linted, not only specified files? Also, do you have any rules set up? From your example you have completely empty config object.

It's linting through all the files of the project but I want it to work on only the files given in eslint.config.js

Can you share your full config? If you are having something else in the configuration array, it will affect results.

@Mr.Hedgehog I've only this in my configuration.

But it's empty. It will not lint anything. Try to set up some rules, like "no-console" and deliberately break them in the files you want to check and files you don't want to check. Then run eslint and see if it helps.
